# Почему перед «и» ставится запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Однажды вдалеке мы увидели очертания корабля, и, когда он подошел ближе, все убедились, что это долгожданная помощь с материка, которую ждали еще неделю назад.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что ССП, две основы:

1. мы увидели;
2. все убедились.

*Однажды вдалеке **мы увидели** очертания корабля, и, когда он подошел ближе, **все убедились**, что это долгожданная помощь с материка, которую ждали еще неделю назад.*